# How did you solve Mongoose Schema not been registered for model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm learning the mean stack and when I try to start the server using

```
npm start
```

I get an exception saying that:

> schema hasn't been registered for model 'Post'. Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Here is my code inside /models/Posts.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String, 
    upvotes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

As I can see the schema should be registered for the model 'Post', but what can be possibly causing the exception to be thrown?

In my app.js the order is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');

require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');
```

In my controller I had imported my mongoose models like this :-

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
```

but still getting this issue.

How did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you try as module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema); ?

Comment: & this would be in my Posts.js ? where I have created my model, I also export it. right ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @CanerDağlı this worked. But when I keep it in a seperate file for e.g. Posts.js this does not work somehow. I had to add all the code for model schema in my index.js. Any suggestion about this ?

Comment: Do you still get the same error when it is in a seperate file?

Comment: Yes, I get same error. Not sure why. Is there some issue with how I am importing the file ? I did:  require("./path/filename")

Comment: Maybe you should check those examples about the usage of module.export; http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/

Maybe there is something wrong with the order of including modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your mongoose model like this in your controllers:

```
var Posts = mongoose.model('Posts');
var Comments = mongoose.model('Comments');
```

Then you can use Posts and Comments like this:

```
Posts.find(function(err, posts){
     //posts
});

Comments.find(function(err, comments){
     //comments
});
```

Comment: So I tried this :  module.exports & this worked. Thanks a lot !